# Java function override

Tags: java

Lets say I have class A and Class B. Then, in main, is it possible to get back the return value of class A? I am doing homework right now, but cant seem to get them right, so here the example I want to ask...

```
public class A
{
    private double total=10;
    public double test()
    {
    return total;
    }
}

  public class B extends A
{
    private double totalB=20;
    public double test()
    {
    return (super.test()+10);
    }
}

public class C
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    double Sum;
    B FTest = new B();
    System.out.println("I want to get back return value of class A for calculate\n"+FTest.test()/2);
    //So the answer i want to get is suppose to be 5
    System.out.println("Again i want to use return value of class A\n"+FTest.test()*10);
   //Here the value i want to get is 10*10 = 100
}
}
```

Answer i got

```
I want to get back return value of class A for calculate
30.0
Again i want to use return value of class A
300.0
```

The answer i want

```
I want to get back return value of class A for calculate
5
Again i want to use return value of class A
100
```

So the direct question i asking is am i able to call test() method in Class A in main using the 
B object. If can, how?

Comment: Can you modify this Java into something that actually compiles, please?

Comment: Also, since this is homework, can you include the *actual* question that is being asked; it's not clear whether you've understood what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Dancrumb, code edited, as for the homework question, the question is actually different but is required to use override. So now i just wondering that if i am able to take back return value of test method in class A instead of class B using object B declared in main for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created an object of Class `B`, You can get the values for variable you have initialized in Class `A`, unless you modified the Class B's `test()` method

Answer (score 1):

The `super` keyword gives you access to superclasses' properties and methods.

Since `total` is private in `A`, you'll need to get it via `A`'s `test` method.

Thus,`B` should become:

```
public class B extends A
{
    private total=20;
    public double test()
    {
        return super.test()+10;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way i could call test method in class A using the object B declared in main? something like FTest.super.test();

Answer (score 0):

here Is the code that I can write ..more over there are many blenders in your submitted code regarding defination of class and variables.. etc.please refer your material

```
        class A
        {
             int total=10;
            public double test()
            {
            return total;
            }
        }

         class B extends A
        {
            private int total=20;
            public double test()
            {

           return total+10;
            }
        }

        public class C
        {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {

            A class1 = new A();
            System.out.println("I want to get back return value of class A for calculate");
            //So the answer i want to get is suppose to be 5
            //If override occur only the second time i invoke the method, then how about i want to use it    back again? For calculation.....
            System.out.println("Again i want to use return value of class A"+class1.test()*10);
           //Here the value i want to get is 10*10 = 100
        }
        }
```

Comment: ok sorry, i edited the code~